# Grakn - Attributes playing roles in Relations vs. Relations having attributes

Tags: attributes, relationship, vaticle-typedb

After going through the grakn dev documentation, I am wondering:

1. a relation can have many role players, incl. attributes, but
2. I can also assign attributes to a relation

what are the pros/cons? Do you have a good example of when it makes sense to do which, and what the consequences of it would be for querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes can both *play* roles in relations and be *owned*. Which you need should be driven by your domain model and what you're trying to achieve, rather than what's possible.

One general idea is that each role player adds semantic information that helps define the meaning of the relation instance it is playing a role in. On the other hand, owning an attribute adds additional information to a piece of data that is already meaningful.

So we might imagine that `contract` between `person` and `company` has person and company as role players, and we add a `date` attribute for when the contract starts and ends. However, if we defined the contract instead to be a semantically  different `limited-time-contract` it might make more sense to have `start-date`, `end-date`, `person`, `company` to be playing roles in the `limited-time-contract` relation.

A slightly different way to think about it is that attributes playing roles give an extra piece of context in how that attribute is acting in the relation. A direct ownership carries no further information.